# Design advice for OpenGL ES 2 / iOS GLKit

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

I'd like to build an app using the new GLKit framework, and I'm in need of some design advice.  I'd like to create an app that will present up to a couple thousand "bricks" (objects with very simple geometry).  Most will have identical texture, but up to a couple hundred will have unique texture.  I'd like the bricks to appear every few seconds, move into place and then stay put (in world coords).  I'd like to simulate a camera whose position and orientation are controlled by user gestures.

The advice I need is about how to organize the code.  I'd like my model to be a collection of bricks that have a lot more than graphical data associated with them:

- Does it make sense to associate a view-like object with each handle geometry, texture, etc.?
- Should every brick have it's own vertex buffer?
- Should each have it's own GLKBaseEffect?
- I'm looking for help organizing what object should do what during setup, then rendering.

I hope I can stay close to the typical MVC pattern, with my GLKViewController observing model state changes, controlling eye coordinates based on gestures, and so on.

Would be much obliged if you could give some advice or steer me toward a good example.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to the models, I think an approach analogous to the relationship between `UIImage` and `UIImageView` is appropriate. So every type of brick has a single vertex buffer,`GLKBaseEffect`, texture and whatever else. Each brick may then appear multiple times just as multiple `UIImageViews` may use the same `UIImage`. In terms of keeping multiple reference frames, it's actually a really good idea to build a hierarchy essentially equivalent to `UIView`, each containing some transform relative to the parent and one sort being able to display a model.

From the GLKit documentation, I think the best way to keep the sort of camera you want (and indeed the object locations) is to store it directly as a `GLKMatrix4` or a `GLKQuaternion` — so you don't derive the matrix or quaternion (plus location) from some other description of the camera, rather the matrix or quaternion directly is the storage for the camera.

Both of those classes have methods built in to apply rotations, and `GLKMatrix4` can directly handle translations. So you can directly map the relevant gestures to those functions.

The only slightly non-obvious thing I can think of when dealing with the camera in that way is that you want to send the **inverse** to OpenGL rather than the thing itself. Supposing you use a matrix, the reasoning is that if you wanted to draw an object at that location you'd load the matrix directly then draw the object. When you draw an object at the same location as the camera you want it to end up being drawn at the origin. So the matrix you have to load for the camera is the inverse of the matrix you'd load to draw at that location because you want the two multiplied together to be the identity matrix.

I'm not sure how complicated the models for your bricks are but you could hit a performance bottleneck if they're simple and all moving completely independently. The general rule when dealing with OpenGL is that the more geometry you can submit at once, the faster everything goes. So, for example, an entirely static world like that in most games is much easier to draw efficiently than one where everything can move independently. If you're drawing six-sided cubes and moving them all independently then you may see worse performance than you might expect.

If you have any bricks that move in concert then it is more efficient to draw them as a single piece of geometry. If you have any bricks that definitely aren't visible then don't even try to draw them. As of iOS 5, `GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean` is available, which is a way to pass some geometry to OpenGL and ask if any of it is visible. You can use that in realtime scenes by building a hierarchical structure describing your data (which you'll already have if you've directly followed the `UIView` analogy), calculating or storing some bounding geometry for each view and doing the draw only if the occlusion query suggests that at least some of the bounding geometry would be visible. By following that sort of logic you can often discard large swathes of your geometry long before submitting it.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice. I'll re-look at it in terms of the UIImageView analogy as you suggest.  So far, I've made a few choices: 1)opted to separate the GL stuff from the model, 2)since the bricks can share geometry, put the glGenBuffer and glBufferData at the class level.  3)what's working for me so far is a single base effect owned by the view controller, but passed as a render parameter as the vc iterates the bricks in the scene calling each to render.  In the render, the brick composites it's local transform with the effect's, then calls glDrawArrays.